# Getting EPS imports to respect the original fill rule

Tags: graphics, import, data-format, eps-format, svg-format

One major problem in my attempt to answer to the [CountryData flags question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11338/57) is that the way Mathematica handles filled curves differs from the way SVG and EPS style editors do. The latter two have the option to apply either of two rules, the [non-zero rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonzero-rule) or the [even-odd rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even-odd_rule), with the [non-zero rule being default](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/painting.html#ShapeRenderingProperty). The Windows .NET Framework 4.5 [knows both rules too.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.fillrule.aspx)

Mathematica's`FilledCurve` doc page says:

> Filled curves can be non-convex and intersect themselves.
>   Self-intersecting curves are filled according to an even-odd rule that
>   alternates between filling and not at each crossing.

Unfortunately, since `Import` translates a filled curve as a `FilledCurve` with this even-odd rule, one gets a star that was efficiently coded in SVG with five points as follows:

```
Graphics[{Thickness[0.001388888888888889], 
      {FaceForm[{Blue, Opacity[1.]}], 
       FilledCurve[{{{0, 2, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}}, 
          {{{366.902, 230.137}, {258.902,265.33599999999996}, 
            {326.105, 173.336}, {326.105,286.93799999999993}, 
            {258.902, 194.93800000000002}}}
       ]}}, 
       AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(BTW: I would consider this behavior of `Import` a bug, as it doesn't respect the original's default setting.)

Getting a star, filled as desired, takes twice as much points:

```
Graphics[{FaceForm[Blue], 
  Polygon@{{427.3, 183.3}, {401.5, 218.4}, {360.2, 204.8}, {385.7, 
     240}, {360, 275.2}, {401.5, 261.8}, {427.3, 296.6}, {427.2, 
     253.5}, {468.1, 240}, {427.2, 226.6}}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(and, of course, `Import` doesn't do this automatically.)

> My question is: Is there a way to let `FilledCurve` behave according
>   to a non-zero rule, for instance using some undocumented properties like
>   discussed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/563/undocumented-syntax-of-filledcurve) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/702/57)? If not, would it be doable to
>   automatically break up a `FilledCurve` (that not necessarily contains
>   only straight lines) into separate entities that fill up the original
>   shape as intended?

Comment: This isn't a bug in Import, it's an unfortunate limitation of the current Mathematica graphics language.  Import's job is to create the best Mathematica representation of the input file as possible.  The Mathematica graphics language simply doesn't support winding rule fills at this time.

Comment: @ragfield Fair enough. Given the presence of the necessary functionality in Microsoft's framework, it appears the addition of this capability to `FilledCurve` should be quite doable. May I suggest putting this on the wishlist for version 10?

Comment: @ragfield It seems that in Mathematica 12 there are now more filling rules available. See the documentation of `WindingPolygon` . It's a pity that `FilledCurve` does not already make use of this. Is it possible to put this on a To Do list?

Answer (score 1):

We're getting closer. In Mathematica 12, there are now more filling rules available. The documentation of the new function `WindingPolygon` lists the following:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The first star in the question (the one with the minimum number of edges), can now be shown without holes using `WindingPolygon`:

```
Graphics[{Thickness[
   0.001388888888888889], {EdgeForm[{Blue, Opacity[1.]}], 
   FaceForm[{Blue, Opacity[1.]}], 
   WindingPolygon[{{{366.902, 230.137}, {258.902, 
       265.33599999999996}, {326.105, 173.336}, {326.105, 
       286.93799999999993}, {258.902, 194.93800000000002}}}]}}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The filling rule we need here("NonzeroRule") is the default for `WindingPolygon`.

Alas, `FilledCurve` does not know these filling rules (yet?)